# How do I utilize custom FaultExceptions from within a .net 2.0 app?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-2.0, asmx, asp.net-2.0

I'm consuming a modern WCF web service written in .net 4.5 inside an app written in .net 2.0.

BasicHttp binding is used to allow me to access the WCF as an asmx.

Inside the WCF are custom FaultExceptions.

Is there any way that I can utilize these custom FaultExceptions in my .net 2.0 app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASMX technology did not support faults properly.  Your custom `FaultExceptions` should be translated to a [`SoapException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx). You should then be able to look at the XML in the `Detail` property of the `SoapException`.

Comment: Thanks.  As a matter of fact I was just writing catch (SoapException ex) as I saw this answer come in.  =)